# How to count vowels and consonants in pandas dataframe (both uppercase and lowercase)?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text, feature-extraction

Here's my data

```
No  Body
1   DaTa, Analytics
2   StackOver.
```

Here's my expected output

```
No  Body                 Vowels   Consonant  
1   DaTa, Analytics.     5        8        
2   StackOver.           3        6
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can count # of vowels using a very simple RegEx and # of consonants is a number of all letters minus # of vowels:

```
In [121]: df['Vowels'] = df.Body.str.lower().str.count(r'[aeiou]')

In [122]: df['Consonant'] = df.Body.str.lower().str.count(r'[a-z]') - df['Vowels']

In [123]: df
Out[123]:
   No             Body  Vowels  Consonant
0   1  DaTa, Analytics       5          8
1   2       StackOver.       3          6
```

PS [`y` may be either a vowel or a consonant ...](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/is-the-letter-y-a-vowel-or-a-consonant)

Comment: You forget `y` ;)

Comment: @jezrael, [IMO there is no clear rule, whether `y` is a vowel or a consonant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/is-the-letter-y-a-vowel-or-a-consonant)

Comment: In slovak language `y` is `Vowel` ;)

Comment: OK, nice to know

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to apply `str.extractall` with an or'd condition to effectively break things into two columns, then groupby the index and take a count of the columns, eg:

```
counts = (
    df.Body.str.extractall('(?i)(?P<vowels>[aeiou])|(?P<consonants>[a-z])')
    .groupby(level=0).count()
)
```

This works because the `(?i)` of the regex specifies the expression should be case insensitive, and `[aeiou]` captures all vowels into the first match group (or column) and then `[a-z]` will capture all other letters that the first group hasn't captured (everything but vowels).

Gives you:

```
   vowels  consonants
0       5           8
1       3           6
```

Then assign/join as appropriate to your original DF.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with parameter `re.I` for ignore case:

```
import re
df['Vowels'] = df['Body'].str.count(r'[aeiou]', flags=re.I)
df['Consonant'] = df['Body'].str.count(r'[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzy]', flags=re.I)
print (df)
   No             Body  Vowels  Consonant
0   1  DaTa, Analytics       5          8
1   2       StackOver.       3          6
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
vowels = set("AEIOUaeiou")
cons = set("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ")

df['Vowels'] = [sum(1 for c in x if c in vowels) for x in df['Body']]
df['Consonents'] = [sum(1 for c in x if c in cons) for x in df['Body']]

print (df)
```

Comment: how I get the sample.csv ?

Comment: I just created that to test my code. Ignore that. I have edited my answer

Comment: This is great, it ispiresme to other part of work, thanks